# xml layout not showing in another xml layout using LayoutInflater in Android

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I am trying to add one xml layout in another xml layout using LayoutInflater.
but its not showing.

Please check my source code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class CustomeWebView extends Activity {
RelativeLayout relLay;
WebView webview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_new);
    relLay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_relLay);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplication()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v_child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    relLay.addView(v_child);
}
}
```

main xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_relLay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#0B7A3B" >
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

child xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/row_relLay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#F70925">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/row_webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:visibility="gone">
    </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change webview visibility to visible.

Comment: nothing... its showing blank white screen...

Comment: Yes because there is not content in webview. Please load url in webview then after you can see something.

Comment: But for testing I already set layout color (RED)..   android:background="#F70925"

Comment: I also load url but not get success yet.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line `android:fillViewport="true"` to your ScrollView. It should do the trick.

When set to true, this attribute causes the scroll view’s child to expand to the height of the ScrollView if needed. When the child is taller than the ScrollView, the attribute has no effect.

Note :

1. You should remove the RelativeLayout surrounding your ScrollView in main_new.xml
2. You Should remove the LinearLayout surrounding your RelativeLayout in row.xml

Both are unnecessary